# How to run two procedures in ada

Tags: ada

I have an ada program that has a main procedure, now I want to add another procedure but I got an error saying "end of file expected, file can have only one compilation unit". I did some looking an I think it is because you can only have 1 procedure per file. Do I have to create another file and put the procedure alone in that? If so how would I compile both the codes and run it? Can someone show me how I would be able to compile both and run the whole file together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ada beginner Stack program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182824/ada-beginner-stack-program)

Comment: Simon's comment is bang on. But if one procedure calls the other, you can simply declare the other local to the first (i.e. in its declaration region)

Comment: What would the declaration syntax look like? Would I have to name the file?

Comment: The answer to the question "how would I compile both the codes and run it" depends on what compiler you're using.  I assume you're using GNAT, but if not please let us know what compiler you're using.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler says, you can only have one compilation unit per file.  A main program is compilation unit, which is a procedure.

If you want one program to run two procedures which both are compilation units, when you can do it like this:

```
with One_Procedure,
     Another_Procedure;
procedure Sequential is
begin
   One_Procedure;
   Another_Procedure;
end Sequential;
```

If you want to run the two procedures in parallel do it like this:

```
with One_Procedure,
     Another_Procedure;
procedure Parallel is
   task One;
   task Another;

   task body One is
   begin
      One_Procedure;
   end One;

   task body Another is
   begin
      Another_Procedure;
   end Another;
begin
   null;
end Parallel;
```

The procedures may of course also be declared in the declarative region of the main program or in some packages.

Comment: Note that "only one compilation unit per file" is **not** an Ada rule.  It's a GNAT restriction.  Not all Ada compilers have this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Both recent GNATs and GPRbuild have options for indicating which units of a file you want compiled: that's `-gnateINNN` for `gcc`, and `-eInn` for `gprbuild`, as [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Switches-for-gcc.html#Switches-for-gcc).

Another option is to become familiar with `gnatchop` for extracting compilation units from files, and with `-m` for minimal recompilation; the latter prevents having to compile the world only because of running `gnatchop` when an edit has not "semantically" touched all compilation units in a file. GNAT then ignores time stamps. I sometimes run commands like

```
gnatchop -r -w -c allofit.ada && gnatmake -Ptest -m someunit.adb
```

where `someunit.adb` is generated for compilation unit `Someunit` (a procedure, a package) contained in file `allofit.ada`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 1 main procedure but several procedures within main procedure.

```
procedure main is
    ...text...

    procedure sub1 () is
    begin
        ...text...
    end sub1;

    procedure sub2 () is
    begin
        ...text...
    end sub2;

    ...text...
end main;
```